# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined while creating pagination with datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables, pagination

I getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined while creating pagination with datatable. below is my html enclose the table. I did google and some threads says td in head and tbody be same. I have same thead and tbody td but still getting error. I am not sure if it's not working due script in the same file means datatable has limitation to call more than once in file or is that html entities in td?

js :

```
jQuery('#mytableid').DataTable();
```

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2" class="col-common-width">fsfs</th>
      <th rowspan="2" class="col-common-width">sfsdf</th>
      <th rowspan="2" class="col-common-width">sfdsf</th>
      <th rowspan="2" class="col-common-width">fadsf</th>
      <th rowspan="2" class="col-common-width">fsaf</th>
      <th rowspan="2" class="col-common-width">ssafsd</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
                  <tr> 
          <td>sfas</td>
          <td>sfsfs
</td>
          <td>dsfsdf</td>
          <td>sgdg</td>
          <td>gsd</td>
          <td>dg</td>
        </tr>
              <tr> 
          <td>gsdf</td>
          <td>sgd
</td>
          <td>gsdf</td>
          <td>487</td>
          <td>442</td>
          <td>90.76%</td>
        </tr>
              <tr> 
          <td>fsgfd</td>
          <td>I&amp;I
</td>
          <td>sgfdg</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>5.26%</td>
        </tr>
              <tr> 
          <td>dsgfdg</td>
          <td>I&amp;I
</td>
          <td>dsgdf</td>
          <td>5,890</td>
          <td>3,707</td>
          <td>62.94%</td>
        </tr>
              <tr> 
          <td>gsdfg</td>
          <td>gdfg
</td>
          <td>gdsgf</td>
          <td>dfgdf</td>
          <td>88</td>
          <td>26.27%</td>
        </tr>
              <tr> 
          <td>dgdf</td>
          <td>IM
</td>
          <td>dgd</td>
          <td>4,998</td>
          <td>4,528</td>
          <td>90.60%</td>
        </tr>
              <tr> 
          <td>dgdf</td>
          <td>gdf
</td>
          <td>gsdf</td>
          <td>464</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>6.47%</td>
        </tr>
              <tr> 
          <td>dfgdf</td>
          <td>dgdfg
</td>
          <td>dfgd</td>
          <td>10,926</td>
          <td>5,762</td>
          <td>52.74%</td>
        </tr>
              <tr> 
          <td>dfgdf</td>
          <td>dfgdf
</td>
          <td>dgdf</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>80.00%</td>
        </tr>
              <tr> 
          <td>dfgdf</td>
          <td>dfgdf
</td>
          <td>dgdf</td>
          <td>1,418</td>
          <td>1,091</td>
          <td>76.94%</td>
        </tr>
              <tr> 
          <td>gdfg</td>
          <td>gdgd
</td>
          <td>gsdf</td>
          <td>265</td>
          <td>121</td>
          <td>45.66%</td>
        </tr>
              <tr> 
          <td>dgdFgdfMD</td>
          <td>gdf
</td>
          <td>HCPs</td>
          <td>1,348</td>
          <td>1,155</td>
          <td>85.68%</td>
        </tr>
              <tr> 
          <td>dgsdf</td>
          <td>Igdfg
</td>
          <td>dfgdfg</td>
          <td>708</td>
          <td>649</td>
          <td>91.67%</td>
        </tr>
              <tr> 
          <td>Total</td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>26,9fg48</td>
          <td>17,6g48</td>
          <td>65.4fg9%</td>
        </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: Start with something that works, then work from there.  The pdatatables wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatables/info) provides a starting set of scripts/html/js that will get a datatable working.  Once you have that working, you then change the Ids to match yours then the table content to match yours.  At the point it fails, you should be able to work out why (if you don't make too many changes in one go).

Comment: There's not enough information provided in your question to provide a suitable solution.  eg there's no `<table>` tag or indication of what you mean by "script in same file".  Datatable should be able to be applied to separately to separate tables on the same page.

Comment: Having said that.  It looks like the `rowspan=2` is causing the problem - remove that and your HTML (as implied in the question, not provided) works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/yLfq2trm/

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you! I jus want to know that I am using datatable on ajax success call so already using datatable and calling one more time in other case on ajax success call in the same file. So i thing its for single use only.

Comment: Nope, you can call it multiple times for different elements on the same page.  It's a well-written plugin that handles this correctly.  https://jsfiddle.net/bnpL5gs3/   It's the rowspan= that's causing the issue.

Comment: @freedomn-m yes its seem working without rowspan="2" but why this is happing in my case. Do you have any idea, why this happening with rowspan?